# The blank final field writer may not have been initialized

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, encryption

I am using SharedPreferences to store some information from my app, but is creating an Object for Activities to manage this. I am also using [encrypted-userprefs](https://github.com/sveinungkb/encrypted-userprefs) in this class. I get the error "The blank final field writer may not have been initialized" in

```
public StoredPrefsHandler(Context context, boolean secure) throws SecurePreferencesException {
```

I have no idea why this occurs, and especially when it seems to work in a similar class I have. Here are the relevant code. Note that I have defined writer already.

```
public class StoredPrefsHandler {
    public static class SecurePreferencesException extends RuntimeException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3051912281127821578L;

        public SecurePreferencesException(Throwable e) {
            super(e);
        }
    }

    // Stripped down part, more fields unrelevant to the problem have been hidden
    private final String SP_LOCATION = "org.conrogatio.lazyrace.prefs";
    private final String SSP_LOCATION = "org.conrogatio.lazyrace.secureprefs";
    private String LOCATION;
    private Context c;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static final String KEY_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
private static final String SECRET_KEY_HASH_TRANSFORMATION = "SHA-256";
private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    private final Cipher writer;
    private final Cipher reader;
    private final Cipher keyWriter;

    /**
     * This will initialize an instance of the SecurePreferences class
     * 
     * @param context
     *            your current context.
     * @throws SecurePreferencesException
     */
    public StoredPrefsHandler(Context context, boolean secure) throws SecurePreferencesException {
        c = context;
        secured = secure;
        if (secured) {
            LOCATION = SSP_LOCATION;
            deviceId = Secure.getString(c.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            try {
                this.writer = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
                this.reader = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
                this.keyWriter = Cipher.getInstance(KEY_TRANSFORMATION);
                initCiphers(deviceId + SSP_SALT);
                this.prefs = c.getSharedPreferences(SSP_LOCATION, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                throw new SecurePreferencesException(e);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new SecurePreferencesException(e);
            }
        } else {
            LOCATION = SP_LOCATION;
        }
        update();
    }
```

Comment: If you pass _secure=false_ to this constructor, final fields _writer_, _reader_ and _keyWriter_ remain uninitialised. Thus compiler complains. Set them to i.e null if you know you don't need them.

Comment: This seems to work if also making them non-final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If secure==false, the writer, reader and keyWriter will be uninitialized. This can be solved by initialize them earlier, but then also set them to be non-final.

```
private final Cipher writer;
private final Cipher reader;
private final Cipher keyWriter;
```

becomes

```
private Cipher writer = null;
private Cipher reader = null;
private Cipher keyWriter = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize the finals like this:

```
 private final Cipher writer=null;
 private final Cipher reader=null;
 private final Cipher keyWriter=null;
```

Comment: Since I also have to re-initialize them later if secure==true, the final parameter needs to be removed

Comment: you can make them non-final